# java.lang.NullPointerException Error While trying to get Location

Tags: android, location

I am trying to make an application that takes the location and sends that data, everything was fine till 10 min ago. Now I got an error and I couldn't find what it is. Any help, thank you...

Some of my codes below...

```
...
...
     Location mCurrentLocation;

private final static int
        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
LocationClient mLocationClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}



...
...


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        tv.setText("slm"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    }
```

And the error I get is ...

```
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.example.testapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:186)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-19 10:58:10.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: MainActivity.java:186 - where is 186 line in MainActivity

Comment: it is  tv.setText("slm"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());

Comment: mCurrentLocation is null or  tv is null, you should check both

Comment: mostly tv null, he has `new LocationClient(this, this, this);`

Comment: mCurrentLocation shouldnt be null because of mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
and tv shouldnt because of TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Comment: both can be null because you don't create this objects using 'new'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help activating Google's location service solved my problem.

Comment: You activated through locationClient.connect()?

Answer (score 1):

Check for null before you set the locations latitude in the TextView. You can't be sure that `getLastLocation()` returns a valid location Object immediatly because it's a non-blocking call.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    if(mCurrentLocation != null)
        tv.setText("slm"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
}
```